# Rails association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't even know where to start to explain my problem, so please bear with me :( !

I have two models; Product and Category - Product has_one Category and Category belongs_to Product

## Product model

id
name
description
brand
merchant
price
image
link
category

## Category model

id
name
product_id

---

Ok so now I'm looping through an XML feed create products like so:

```
Product.create(:name => node.xpath("./text/name/text()").inner_text.downcase, 
               :description => node.xpath("./text/desc/text()").inner_text,
               :brand => node.xpath("./brand/text()").inner_text,
               :merchant => node.xpath("../@name").inner_text,
               :category => Category.find_by_name(node.xpath("./cat/text()").inner_text.downcase),
               :price => "£" + node.xpath("./price/btext()").inner_text)
```

This appears to run great, until I look at what it's produced in the database... Here's the output from both tables.

## Products table
(abridged version, contains 10,000+ records)

id: 1
....
....
....
category:     <---- empty for all 10,000+ records... err wtf? Surely should be a category ID or name

## Categories table 
 (only contains 8 records, one for each category)

id: 1
name: socks
product_id: 10662 <---- err wtf?

id: 2
name: combinations
product_id: 10658 <---- err wtf?

id: 3
name: shoes
product_id: 9954 <---- err wtf?

id: 4
name: nightwear
product_id: 10653 <---- err wtf?

id: 5
name: hats
product_id: 10655 <---- err wtf?

id: 6
name: shorts
product_id: 10221 <---- err wtf?

id: 7
name: jeans
product_id: 9973 <---- err wtf?

id: 8
name: trainers
product_id: 8072 <---- err wtf?

To be honest I'm so confused, I'm not sure what I want to see anymore :-/

I just want the two tables to link together lol. Am I missing something fundamental here!?

Comment: Ok everyone, it's working now. However, it's now setting the category_id to '1' for all products!? I guess it's something wrong with this line: :category_id => Category.find_by_name(node.xpath("./cat/text()").inner_text.downcase)

Comment: Ah Ha! I cracked it. The line should have been :category instead of :category_id -> :category => Category.find_by_name(node.xpath("./cat/text()").inner_text.downcase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of changes you need to make. Firstly, your model structure should look like this:

```
class Product
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category
  has_many :products
end
```

Secondly, your products table should have a category_id, not a category and your categories table should not have a product_id at all. Your code example should then run properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship is backwards. If you want a product to be in a single category you need:

Product
`belongs_to :category`

Category
`has_many :products`

Comment: That's your other problem.  You want `has_many` products, not `has_one` (unless there really is a 1:1 mapping of categories->products)

Comment: Ok. I get your comments, I have just tried it and now both product.category and category.product_id fields are empty for all records, which isn't right either.

Do I need to kill the product_id column on the categories table and create a category_id on the products table? In other words reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use has_one / belongs to, only *one* of the models ends up containing the id of the other.  In your case, since `Category belongs_to Product`, the `categories` table needs a `product_id` column, where it'll store the ID of the product it belongs to.

But if `Product has_one Category` (this also applies to `has_many`), it *doesn't* need a `category_id` column - Rails knows that to find the category (c) for a given product (p), it can just look through the `categories` table for a category where product_id == p.id.

From the code you posted, it looks like Rails is doing what it should - even though the relationship is accessible from both models, only the model that has the `belongs_to` directive has any relationship data stored in its table.  In fact, Rails is smart enough to know that when you specify the {:category => cat} option when creating a Product, it should actually change the `categories` table - and it does.  That's why you're seeing `product_id`s in your `categories` table, and nothing in your `products` table (and the column `products.category` doesn't even need to exist - the relationship will work fine without it).

**With that said,** I suspect that a Product should be able to belong to more than one Category, and , likewise, a Category should be able to contain more than one Product.  In that case, you'll want to use [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) in *both* models, and create the join table `categories_products` to connect them...

Hope this clears things up!